# Cassandra nodes taking different loads while starting initially

Tags: cassandra

I am using virtual box for configuring cassandra nodes, i am able to start a cluster with three nodes, i didn't gave any initial tokens while starting for all three nodes, the three nodes are taking different loads one is taking 85% another 11% and the last is taking 4% can  any one have idea why the nodes are not balanced with in these three nodes while starting up.

Comment: What partitioner are you using, and what does it say when you run `nodetool ring`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get even data distribution you need to manually specify the tokens in your conf.

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/initialize/token_generation

Comment: Is this the case even when replication_factor=<numberofnodes>?

Comment: No, but given that you probably chose cassandra for its ability to scale, you will likely still want to intelligently pick your tokens.